# SIEMENS AFCI breaker trips with load on any outlets along the circuit

Tags: circuit-breaker, load

Everything working on this circuit for couple years. And suddenly get breaker trip with any load. Suspect a faulty breaker first.
However, issue stays the same after replacing the breaker with a known good one (one working without issue on another circuit). I know it might be neutral-to-ground fault.
My question is if the N-G issue happen with one outlet, will that affect all outlets along the circuit with load plug in that trip breaker? Should I check all outlets box along the circuit path for N-G issue?

Comment: it should be specific to a branch

Comment: I have seen ants do it too.  I have had it on two occasions where the light switch box was packed full of dead ants.  I am guessing that one ant dies of electrocution, it attracts others and they keep coming.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a neutral-ground short anywhere in the branch will cause a GFCI to trip with any load on the branch. Because all of the loads on a branch have their neutrals in parallel and their grounds in parallel, a N-G short anywhere along will allow the neutral current to leak to ground.

As @GeorgeAnderson wrote, it could well be rodent damage.

Answer (score 4):

A good possibility is rodent damage.  I had that happen twice in a previous home. [image: electrocuted mouse] Exactly the same circumstances...tripping breakers with no load.

EDIT:  circled the rodent to make it more clear

Comment: Hard to tell what that picture is indicating...

Comment: @FreeMan you apparently missed the critter in the middle of the pic.  I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah, yeah. From here, it looks like just a dirty bit of insulation.

Comment: @FreeMan  I edited the pic to highlight what I was talking about.

Comment: :thumbsup: Also, edited to remove the 2nd image.

Comment: @FreeMan  thanks, for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to delete the duplicate image,  it was like "both or nothing".